# What does `: Hold[$IterationLimit]` mean?

Tags: programming, pattern-matching, core-language

In [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24683/7292), what does the  `: Hold[$IterationLimit]` part of the following construct do?

```
cfRemainders[x_, iter_: Hold[$IterationLimit]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The original complete definition is

```
cfRemainders[x_, iter_: Hold[$IterationLimit]] := 
 NestWhileList[FractionalPart[1/#] &, FractionalPart[x], # != 0 &, 1, ReleaseHold[iter]]
```

The `iter_ : Hold[$IterationLimit]` makes `iter` an [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) argument with the default value `Hold[$IterationLimit]` if the argument is omitted.

Secondly, by using `Hold`, `$IterationLimit` is not evaluated until `cfRemainders` is actually called and `ReleaseHold[iter]` is executed.  So if a user resets `$IterationLimit`, subsequent calls to `cfRemainders` will respect it.

---

One question might be why did I do it this way.
(My feeling is that I'm overlooking something and someone will suggest a better way to limit the number of times an iteration occurs.)

Without some limit on `NestWhileList`, calling `cfRemainders` on an irrational number would run forever (or until Mma ran out of memory).  `$IterationLimit` seemed like a convenient system variable to use (`$RecursionLimit` is another and one can argue which seems more appropriate).  But without `Hold` in the definition

```
cfRemainders[x_, iter_: $IterationLimit] := ...
```

the current value of `$IterationLimit` is substituted and the definition is equivalent to (assuming `$IterationLimit == 4096`)

```
cfRemainders[x_, iter_: 4096] := ...
```

(You can check with `? cfRemainders`.)  In this case, if a user changes `$IterationLimit`, `cfRemainders` is unaffected.

Alternative definition could be to set my own arbitrary limit or make the argument `iter` mandatory:

```
cfRemainders[x_, iter_: 1000] := ...
cfRemainders[x_, iter_] := ...
```

Another good question is why worry about this, when I neglected to put a restriction on `x` to be numeric, which would be helpful, too:

```
cfRemainders[x_?NumericQ, iter_: Hold[$IterationLimit]] := ...
```

In fact, I think I'll go edit my other answer.

Comment: I think your method is quite reasonable, but if you seek another you could also do something like: `f[x_, iter_: -1] := [. . ., iter /. -1 :> $IterationLimit]` Or, you could you Options.

Answer (score 4):

What this does is set a default value for `iter`, meant for use if `cfRemainders` is called with only one argument. The default value for `iter` in this case is `$IterationLimit`, and the `Hold[]` enclosing it means `cfRemainders` will use `$IterationLimit` symbol for the new rule. If there was no enclosing `Hold[]`, `$IterationLimit` would have been replaced with the Integer value assciated with it, in the new rule defined for `cfRemainders`. This makes `cfRemainders` more robust\general because, upon calling it, it'll always iterate the appropriate number of times, even if `$IterationLimit` has been changed. Check the differences with  `DownValues[cfRemainders]`, with/without `Hold[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually this is more like a comment to Michael E.'s answer than an own answer, but it became too long for a comment. I think it is worth mentioning that `$IterationLimit` (and also `$RecursionLimit` and probably some others as well) is somewhat special and thus needs  special treatment: For a "normal" variable it would be quite simple to achieve what Michael wants with something like:

```
 $iterationlimit = 4096;
     Block[{$iterationlimit},cfRemainder[x_, iter_: $iterationlimit] := Print[iter];]
```

Now if you look at `DownValues[cfRemainder]` or just use the followings lines of code you find that it will behave as wanted even without the extra `Hold` and `ReleaseHold`:

```
DownValues[cfRemainders]

(*
==> {HoldPattern[cfRemainders[x_, iter_ : $iterationlimit]] :> 
  Print[iter]}
*)

cfRemainders[10]
Block[{$IterationLimit = 20}, cfRemainders[10]]
```

For some deeper reason out of my knowledge that doesn't work for `$IterationLimit` as it seems to not behave as a normal variable within `Block`: it will always have that `OwnValue` even if it is `Block`ed, presumably this is to build an extra barrier against infinite iterations (which would lead to a crash):

```
Block[{$IterationLimit},
      cfRemainders[x_, iter_: $IterationLimit] := Print[ReleaseHold[iter]];
  ];
DownValues[cfRemainders]

(*
==> {HoldPattern[cfRemainders[x_, iter_ : 4096]] :> 
  Print[ReleaseHold[iter]]}
*)
```

There are possibilities to overcome that situation, the trick Micheal used with using an extra `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` is one, here are two ways which avoid the extra `ReleaseHold` but need some more complicated definitions:

**Variant 1:**

```
ClearAll[cfRemainders];
Module[{marker},
  cfRemainders[x_, iter_: marker] := Print[iter];
  DownValues[cfRemainders] = 
    ReplaceAll[DownValues[cfRemainders], marker :> $IterationLimit];
```

];

**Variant 2:**

```
ClearAll[cfRemainders];
Block[{$IterationLimit},
       OwnValues[$IterationLimit] = {};
   cfRemainders[x_, iter_: $IterationLimit] := Print[iter];
]
```

By looking at the `DownValues[cfRemainders]` you can check that both these variants will put an unevaluated `$IterationLimit` into the definition and will work as expected. While I think that the second variant is somewhat more elegant I have the feeling that it might undermine the extra barriers against inifinite recursions and might be dangerous in certain circumstances. So I'd probably go with version 1 which I think should be safe. I'm also  quite sure that there are even better ways to put that unevaluated `$IterationLimit` into the optional part of such a function definition that I couldn't make up...